# Get all networks of connected nodes (Logic puzzle)

Tags: c#, .net, logic, .net-fiddle

I know this is a question which is more about logic than an actual programming issue, but I hope that someone may guide me into the correct direction to solve this. Look at it like the advent programming riddles :)

I have nodes, that are connected with each other over a port. I know the nodes and I know all relations. Now I need to get all possible networks.

To further clarify what I need, I made the following draft:
Image of the network layout: https://ibb.co/51zmkfj

Legend:

- A-F: Nodes
- 1-5: Relations
- 6: Redundant relation (In case node D is
  out of order)
- I-IV: Networks I need to get in a List (All nodes per
  network, therefore a node can be in multiple networks)
- V: Redundant network which I must get in a separate
  list (With source and target node)

Please note, that the network can be much bigger and there may be more than one of these redundant networks

As written, I need these networks I-V. I tried various things and got a version working for I-IV, but it is a lot of code and I am probably overthinking the whole thing.

My approach:

- looping through the relations and creating a `Dictionary<int, List<String>>` with a random int identifier and the id+portNumber as a unique string of all relations that are connected with each other.
- Then I do a nested foreach with the Dictionary to compare each entry with the other entries to find any duplicates and Groups that are not complete.
- Then I remove these wrong groups from the Dictionary.
- After that, I remove the portNumber from all values in the list of the dictionary.

I also made a .NET Fiddle which is prepared with the data exactly as in the image above.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/SQnZYs

Comment: Have you considered a graph database? its the type of problem they are designed for, and have a query language which can help you solve problems like this without iterative code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/graph-introduction

Comment: @TheGeneral that sounds good, but it is probably an overkill for my use case as there are on average 15-20Nodes which will be connected and this seems to be great for big data. Also I would require a server running for this which I would like to omit whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone with a bit of networking experience I'd first like to point out that you can't plug multiple cables into the same port like that

I can see a couple of approaches here but you'll need to add some more information to your data model, such as a way of labelling a backup link as a seperate connection that doesn't get involved in a 'normal' network and therefore needs to be segregated.

The big thing though is that your terms need more refined definitions:

| Object | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| `Node` | A collection of `Port`s (including `Backup` versions of those `Port`s). |
| `Port` | An object that can belong to one `Network` and has an arbitrary number of `Connection`s. |
| `Connection` | Links two `Port`s, contained by a single `Network`. |
| `Network` | A collection of `Port`s and the `Connection`s that link them together. |
| `Backup` | A `Port`, `Connection` or `Network` that is separate from the normal set such than `Backup Port`s and `Backup Connection`s exist exclusively in `Backup Network`s. |

Ok that last one is a bit clumsy, but I think it's a necessary part of the problem in this case. Withou some distinction between a standard link and a backup link you can't separate network `V` from the other networks. Of course not all of those objects are actual classes, they're concepts. The useful minimum seems to be: `Node`, `Port` and `Connection`, with `Network` and `Backup` becoming attributes... although in fairness you could probably replace `Port` with some logic, but it's useful in some ways.

---

With those definitions it should be possible to solve the problem. A psudo-code algorithm for it might be something like this:

```
For each Node:
    For each connected Port with no assigned network:
        Add port to new network.
        Add all Connections to network.
        Repeat for all connected ports.
    For each connected Backup Port with no assigned Backup Network:
        Add port to new Backup Network
        Add all Backup Connections to network.
        Repeat for all connected ports.
```

We could merge the two inner loops into one with the right data structure of course.

And since I'm fond of overly-engineered objects that make my top-level code easier to read (if not always easier to understand), the fact that I had some time on my hands today, and probably in the spirit of Xmas... I wrote a [fun implementation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qKZTnu) for you.

***Caution: not for production use!***

(Seriously, don't even look at all the fun I had with `ToString()` overrides.)

Comment: Thank you for this, I will check it out if it works for my case. Maybe to clarify, this is for a wireless network, and the 'ports' are actually radio transmitters (therefore allowing more than one device to be connected with each other :) ), I just wanted to keep the question "simple". The real structs have a lot more data in it but I omitted it for this

Comment: I think I will be able to use your idea, the only part that is not working is the 'backup' part. This is, because this layout is actually created in a GUI and will look similar to my image and I want to avoid having the user defining any data if not absolutely necessary. I should somehow be able to evaluate the redundant connections to know these backup connections. (Each node has a Type, In my example NodeC and NodeD are Relays and therefore optional for operation, I should be able, after having all networks to extract these backup networks)

Comment: @Xavjer In real networks you'd use something different to distinguish your alternate fail-over links. At minimum the link's metric would be used to determine routing, but we weren't talking about spanning trees and such. I tried to answer the question as asked... maybe I got a tiny bit carried away though :P

Comment: I accepted your answer, as my solution which I now use builds on your base. I used network terms, because it is easier to understand what the purpose is. In reality, it is not a network in proper sense, but a very special one which would just irritate if i would have tried to explain it. But I can work with what you made. I just had to some special logic for the backup network part